# function that splits digits then sums them

Tags: c, function, split, sum, digits

I am trying to solve a problem that requires me to take a number. Use the % and / to take the rightmost number and sum the digits that are separated. Then tell see if the number is divisible by 9.

I have created a function that will separate the rightmost number and then I have tried to take that number and run it through a while loop. The problem that exist is, when I run the while loop. It creates an infinite loop or the output will not be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int loopnum(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    int sum = 0;
    int d = loopnum(num);

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (loopnum(num) > 0) {
        printf("d = %d", d);
        printf(",sum = %d\n", sum);
    }

    if (num % 9 == 0) {
        printf("n = %d is divisible by 9\n", num);
    }
    else {
        printf("n = %d is not divisible by 9\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}

int loopnum(int n)
{
    n = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    return n;
}
```

```
Enter a number:
9
n = 9 is divisible by 9
```

The result of this code is suppose to output d = "the digit" ,sum = 
"digit + sum" and n = "digit" is divisible by 9. for example if I 
input 9. The output would be d = 9, sum = 9.

Comment: `num` never changes in your while loop.

Comment: Also `num` is never initialized for `int d = loopnum(num);`

Comment: You are passing number by value. So the changes done in the function is not reflected in the calling function. You should use pointers.

Comment: You never change `num` so when did you expect `loopnum(num)` to change?

Comment: I expected loopnum(num) to run through the while loop and to extract the digit then sum the digit. I noticed a line to sum the digit is missing in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `loopnum` code is wrong. It will always return zero and therefor the `while` will not loop.

```
int loopnum(int n)
{
    n = n % 10;  // After this n is a number between 0 and 9
    n = n / 10;  // Consequently, when you divide by 10 you'll end up with zero
    return n;
}
```

Your design  requires two things:

1) Return the remainder

2) Change n

To do that you need to pass a pointer to `n`.

Something like:

```
int loopnum(int *n)
{
    int res = *n % 10; 
    *n = *n / 10;
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = 123;
  int sum = 0;
  while(x) sum += loopnum(&x);
  printf("%d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function does not make sense.

```
int loopnum(int n)
{
    n = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    return n;
}
```

For example for `n` equal to `27` you will get

```
n = n % 10;
```

now `n` is equal to `7` and then

```
n = n / 10;
```

now `n` is equal to `0`.

So for the number `27` the function returns `0`.

And moreover inside the loop

```
while (loopnum(num) > 0) {
    printf("d = %d", d);
    printf(",sum = %d\n", sum);
}
```

neither `num`, nor `d`, nor `sum` is changed.

There is no great sense to define such a function except that it could itself to output intemediate sums and digits.

Without the function the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int Base    = 10;
        const unsigned int DIVISOR = 9;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int sum = 0;

        unsigned int tmp = n; 
        do
        {
            unsigned int digit = tmp % Base;
            sum += digit;

            printf( "d = %u, sum = %u\n", digit, sum );
        } while ( tmp /= Base );

        printf( "\nn = %u is %sdivisble by %u.\n\n", 
                 n, 
                 sum % DIVISOR == 0 ? "" : "not ", DIVISOR );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its ouutput might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9
d = 9, sum = 9

n = 9 is divisble by 9.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 123456
d = 6, sum = 6
d = 5, sum = 11
d = 4, sum = 15
d = 3, sum = 18
d = 2, sum = 20
d = 1, sum = 21

n = 123456 is not divisble by 9.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```